# Easyui PropertyGrid width problems

Tags: javascript, typescript, jquery-easyui

When creating an easyui propertygrid dynamically the width becomes a little random. Sometimes it clamps to the contents and other times it expands to the full width of the container.

I want it to expand to the full width of the container.

```
let table = $(`<table id="${id}" class="easyui-propertygrid" style="width:100%" data-options=""></table>`);
        this._selector.append(table);

(<any>$(`#${id}`)).propertygrid({
    data: data,
    singleSelect: true,
    showGroup: true,
    showHeader: false,
    fitColumns: true,
    scrollbarSize: 0
});
```

this is basically what I am doing. The selector is a div.

Comment: Can you try to place a functional example here by adding a snippet with the markup and your libraries in it (jQuery and jQuery-easyUI)?

Comment: I did create a jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/Crisium/0es157p3/22/    problem is that it works here.... so I am trying to figure out what the difference is, since this is almost a true copy from our project.